# How to save data frame using saveAsHadoopFile or MultiTextOutputFormat

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

Basically i need to create output file based on the `DataPartition` column.Last column in the data frame

So First row and last row will be saved in `Fundamental.Fundamental.Fundamental.Japan.1.2018-09-24-0937.Full.txt`
and middle row will be saved in `Fundamental.Fundamental.Fundamental.ThirdParty.1.2018-09-24-0937.Full.txt`

```
+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+--------+------------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Fundamental_uniqueFundamentalSet|OrganizationId|OrganizationId_objectTypeId|OrganizationId_objectType|GaapCode|ConsolidationBasis|IsFiling|NonFilingDateTime|NonFilingReason|PrimaryReportingEntityCode|TotalPrimaryReportingShares|LocalLanguageId|Fundamental_effectiveFrom|Fundamental_effectiveFromPlus|Fundamental_effectiveFromPlusNaCode|Fundamental_effectiveTo|Fundamental_effectiveToMinus|Fundamental_effectiveToMinusNACode|ConsolidationBasisId|GaapCodeId|FFAction|!||DataPartition                                                                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+--------+------------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|192730241374                    |4295877894    |404010                     |Organization             |JPG     |Consolidated      |true    |                 |               |A51EF                     |117588807.00000            |505126         |2013-06-29T00:55:15Z     |                             |                                   |9999-12-31T00:00:00Z   |                            |                                  |3013598             |3011577   |I|!|       |file:/C:/Users/u6034690/Desktop/SPARK/trfsmallfffile/Fundamental/FINALSPARK/Fundamental.Fundamental.Fundamental.Japan.1.2018-09-24-0937.Full.txt|
|192730391384                    |4295877894    |404010                     |Organization             |AOG     |Consolidated      |true    |                 |               |A51EF                     |117588807.00000            |505126         |2018-09-19T09:51:46Z     |                             |                                   |9999-12-31T00:00:00Z   |                            |                                  |3013598             |1003042842|I|!|       |file:/C:/Users/u6034690/Desktop/SPARK/trfsmallfffile/Fundamental/FINALSPARK/Fundamental.Fundamental.Fundamental.ThirdParty.1.2018-09-24-0937.Full.txt|
|192730241373                    |4295877894    |404010                     |Organization             |JPG     |Parent            |true    |                 |               |A51EF                     |117588807.00000            |505126         |2013-06-29T00:55:15Z     |                             |                                   |9999-12-31T00:00:00Z   |                            |                                  |3013599             |3011577   |I|!|       |file:/C:/Users/u6034690/Desktop/SPARK/trfsmallfffile/Fundamental/FINALSPARK/Fundamental.Fundamental.Fundamental.Japan.1.2018-09-24-0937.Full.txt|
+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+--------+------------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------+----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Something this sort of things i am looking for which is not working .**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleTextOutputFormat

class RddMultiTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
  override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = NullWritable.get()
  override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = key.asInstanceOf[String]
}

dataframe.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(noOfHashPartitioner)).saveAsHadoopFile(output, classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RddMultiTextOutputFormat], classOf[GzipCodec])
```

Expected Output.

```
Fundamental.uniqueFundamentalSet|^|OrganizationId|^|OrganizationId.objectTypeId|^|OrganizationId.objectType|^|GaapCode|^|ConsolidationBasis|^|IsFiling|^|NonFilingDateTime|^|NonFilingReason|^|PrimaryReportingEntityCode|^|TotalPrimaryReportingShares|^|LocalLanguageId|^|Fundamental.effectiveFrom|^|Fundamental.effectiveFromPlus|^|Fundamental.effectiveFromPlusNaCode|^|Fundamental.effectiveTo|^|Fundamental.effectiveToMinus|^|Fundamental.effectiveToMinusNACode|^|ConsolidationBasisId|^|GaapCodeId|^|FFAction|!|
192730241373|^|4295877894|^|404010|^|Organization|^|JPG|^|Parent|^|True|^||^||^|A51EF|^|117588807.00000|^|505126|^|2013-06-29T00:55:15Z|^||^||^|9999-12-31T00:00:00Z|^||^||^|3013599|^|3011577|^|I|!|
192730241374|^|4295877894|^|404010|^|Organization|^|JPG|^|Consolidated|^|True|^||^||^|A51EF|^|117588807.00000|^|505126|^|2013-06-29T00:55:15Z|^||^||^|9999-12-31T00:00:00Z|^||^||^|3013598|^|3011577|^|I|!|
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a PairedRDD with the key being your output file name and value being the record and then you can call`saveAsHadoopFile()` to save the files the way that you are looking for.

```
import org.json.JSONObject

val dataframe = .... //this is the dataframe that you want to save

val pairedRDD = dataframe.toJSON.rdd.map(row => {
    val record = new JSONObject(row)
    val key = record.getString("DataPartition")

    (key, row)
})

pairedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(noOfHashPartitioner))
    .saveAsHadoopFile("", classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RddMultiTextOutputFormat])
```

This will give you, your desired output.

Comment: So the format in this case is changed ..We don't need in json format ...The format we need to same as mentioned in the question ..Can we do that ?

Comment: @SUDARSHAN I just took json as an example in this case...