# how to do it in spark i.e. iterate groups and save each group as file at a time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge data , which is accumalated each year , quarterly-wise.
This data is skewed a bit , when I try to get all data into one dataframe by repartitoning it into ("year", "quarter") it is shuffling a lot of data on disk spill which is making my job slow , more over only one executor working 80% of the time.

Hence I decided to 
1) get distinct groups of dataframe , grouping by year and quarter-wise.
2) iterate/loop this distinct data frame by group
   fetch the data group where = year of the group
   save this dataframe/grop as parquet file
   continue iteration.

```
In Java we can use for loop on groups
```

but in spark with scala how to do it ?

Comment: hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52624692/1025328) helps you...

Comment: @Suraj Kumar , hi  how to enable the alerts on particular tag ?

Comment: @Tzach Zohar can you please help me

Comment: @PrasadKhode thankx for quick reply . but how can I group by data in dataframe , each group should be collected in a new dataframe , this dataframe should be send to the function which writes as parquet file

Comment: @PrasadKhode by the way i am using spark-sql 2.3.1 one with scala-2.11 v

Comment: @Shankar Koirala any idea sir